# MongoDB group by date

Tags: php, mongodb, date, group-by

I have a collection in mongodb named "notifications", what I want is, to query all notifications and group them by "date". I have a field in notifications collection named "date_created" which has MongoDate() object in it, so what I want in the output is,

Notifications grouped by => "Today" which has all notifications that are created today
Notifications grouped by => "yesterday" which has all notifications that are created yesterday,

and the list goes on day wise.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $pipeline= array( '$group' => array( "_id" => '$col2',
                                                            'col1' => array('$sum' => '$col1') ,
                                                             'col3' => array('$sum' => '$col3'),
                                                              'col4' => array('$sum' => '$col4')    
                                                        )
                                                    )   ;               

                   if ($this -> publisher_id) {         
                        $pipeline=array_merge($pipeline, array('col5' => $this -> col5value));
                    }

                     $conn = new Mongo();
                     $c = $conn->$db;

                     $result = $c-> command (
                                    array( 
                                        "aggregate" => "tablename",
                                        "pipeline" => 
                                            array($pipeline)
                                    )
                                );
Note : sql query :
select sum(col1) as col1,... from tablename
where col5='value' group by col2
```

Answer (score 0):

How sophisticated does your grouping need to be?  You may just want to use a [sort](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bsort%28%29%7D%7D) on the appropriate field in the document.